# DFS Replication encounters two errors - Not enough space and rpc server error

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, dfs-r

I've recently installed the DFSR service on my DC1 and DC2. Both connected via IPVPN.
Configured it as needed, but there are two problems.
Something in the replication is not going as it should be, although it starts on time, but then the process encounters two errors and the replication is not full.

1) RPC Server error which fixes itself after a couple of minutes:

2) During the replication process, there is a "not enough space" error.

3) On DC1 which is primary for DFS Replication, disk quotas were enabled on the drive which contains the folder which should be replicated. -> is this a problem?

4) The folder should be replicated is about 60 GB.

Is there a way to solve these problems?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: I don't mind, but I'm sure the Israeli Ministry of Finance would appreciate it if you obfuscate your FQDNs and other sensitive details :-)

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you have sufficient disk space, not just for the 60GB but for the staging folder as well. Microsoft generally recommends that free space equivalent to the total size of the 32 largest files in the replicated folder is available for staging at all times, and during the initial seed of a DFS-R replica maybe even more.

Regarding your Disk Quotas, these will definitely be a problem if you've configured disk limits. If your disk quota is implemented for monitoring purposes (the "do not limit disk usage" option) you should be in the clear.

If you're having problems recovering from the current state, please see [KB2218556](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2218556)

Comment: Is the "Staging Folder" different than the actual folder for replication?